# Match URLs by file path and GET parameters (but not their values)

Tags: python, regex, list, url, match

How can I check if any of my list of URLs match the given `url`? I need URLs to match only if all GET parameter names (not their values) and the path are the same. For example, I have this list:

```
links = [
  "http://example.com/page.php?param1=111&param2=222",
  "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=111&param2=222",
  "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=111&param2=222&someParameterN=NumberN"
  ]

url = "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=NOT111&param2=NOT222"
```

This example is `True` because `url` matches `links[1]`. But how to match it in the most efficient way? I don't know what `url` will looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ideally want to use python's urlparse library.
Parse your url like so:

```
import urlparse
url = "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=NOT111&param2=NOT222"
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query).keys()
```

Then you create a datastructure which looks something like this:

```
seen_pages = set() # Stores all pages you've already seen.
```

And then all your pages to it like so:

```
for page in list_of_pages:
    parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(page)
    current_page = (parsed_url.path, frozenset(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query).keys())
    seen_pages.add(current_page)
```

This stores all your pages in the form: `tuple(link, set(param1,param2))` in a set.

To look up if you've already visited the page, with those exact parameters, simply create the `current_page` structure again and look it up in the set.
Look up and addition to a set is an `O(1)` operation, that is, it is as fast as you can get.

Comment: Nice touch making the data hashable (I'd forgotten about `frozenset`).  You could create a `namedtuple` named something like `ComparableURL` with `path` and `params` fields, and store them in your `seen_pages` set... pretty-printing and .fieldname access for free.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase You're right, I could've used a named tuple, but I felt the length and additional overhead of an extra class would've detracted from the brevity of the answer. That's probably how I'd do it in actual shipping code though.

Comment: Thank you =) But can you show an example how to look it up? Because I am trying to make exactly this action. And is it possible to look up in SET()?

Comment: @passwd it is possible to look up in the set. I'll add an example of the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Python's standard library comes with a package for parsing urls: [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).  Don't try to write your own regexes for this... *especially* if you haven't considered all the weird things that are legal parts of a URL.

I suggest something like below.  `is_url_in_list` is the question you want answered.  It calls `url_file_and_params` to break the URl into the file path and a set of query parameters.  `url_file_and_params` calls `url_params_from_quoted_query` to build the set of parameter names.

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from urllib.parse import parse_qs
from urllib.parse import urlsplit


def url_params_from_quoted_query(query_string):
    # An empty query string would make parse_qs raise a ValueError.
    if '' == query_string:
        return set()
    params_and_values = parse_qs(
      query_string,
      keep_blank_values=True,
      strict_parsing=True,
      )
    params = set(params_and_values)
    return params


def url_file_and_params(url):
    parts = urlsplit(url)
    url_file = parts[2]
    quoted_query = parts[3]
    url_params = url_params_from_quoted_query(quoted_query)
    return url_file, url_params


def is_url_in_list(url_target, url_list):
    target_file, target_params = url_file_and_params(url_target)
    for url in url_list:
        url_file, url_params = url_file_and_params(url)
        if url_file == target_file and url_params == target_params:
            return True
    return False


def main():
    links = [
      "http://example.com/page.php?param1=111&param2=222",
      "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=111&param2=222",
      "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=&param2=222",
      "http://example.com/page2.php",
      "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=111&param2=222&someParameterN=NumberN"
      ]

    url = "http://example.com/page2.php?param1=NOT111&param2=NOT222"
    print(is_url_in_list(url, links))
    return


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

One assumption this code makes is that your URLs are already UTF-8 strings with correctly percent-encoded query strings.  If not, you might need to use [`quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) or [`quote_from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes) before feeding them to `is_url_in_list`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) is your friend )

First compare `links[i].split('?')[0]` with `url.split('?')[0]`

Then if true - split your vars with `'&'`.

I think there exists more optimal way, i'm only a newbee, but this way will works.

Comment: Yes, this can work, but Python comes with the [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), which does exactly this kind of work for you.  For example, it would also handle splitting the query parameters from their values (one more split, on `=`), and building a `dict` out of them.

Comment: One time investment that has paid me back many times over was reading all the one-line descriptions of the [Python standard library's packages](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) and reading all the [Python builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)...  It gave me a good idea what had already been done for me, so I could re-invent... well, less than I used to.

Comment: You are right, there are a lot of information. I think man who try to answer takes more score of points to his knowledge base, so I'm trying to state my map of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [`urllib.parse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) (if you are using Python 3) will help you, or `urlparse.urlparse()` for Python 2.

This function will break the URL up into its various components. Then you can compare all components, or a subset of them as you require. Example (Python 3)

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://example.com/page.php?param1=111&param2=222')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/page.php', params='', query='param1=111&param2=222', fragment='')


>>> url1 = urlparse('http://example.com/page.php?param1=111&param2=222')
>>> url2 = urlparse('http://example.com/page.php?param1=111&param2=222')
>>> url1 == url2
True

>>> url3 = urlparse('http://example.com/page2.php?param2=222&param1=111')
>>> url1 == url3
False
>>> url1.query == url3.query    # same GET params but in different order
False
```

The last example shows that the order of parameters in the query string affects the comparison. You can account for that by using `urllib.parse.parse_qs()`:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(url1.query)
{'param2': ['222'], 'param1': ['111']}
>>> parse_qs(url1.query) == parse_qs(url3.query)
True
```

You can use the `.path` attribute of the `ParseResult` to compare "pages".

As I said, I think that will help you, however, I don't fully understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: This tests all parts of the URL, but passwd only wanted to match a few of them... the file path, and the query parameters (but not their values).  I agree that `urllib.parse` is the way to go, though.